# Add a web service (ASMX) to existing asp.net forms website

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to create a web service in an existing asp.net web forms application, but it isn't working.  The following code describes the service:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
public class TestService: System.Web.Services.WebService {

    public TestService() {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
       //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld(string name) {
        return "Hello " + name;
    }    
}
```

When I try to test this web service, the browser tries to download the service instead of executing it:

[image: service]

Also, if I try to reference the service from another project, I get the following error:

*The document at the url `http://localhost:64925/services/TestService.asmx` was not recognized as a known document type.
The error message from each known type may help you fix the problem:
- Report from 'XML Schema' is 'The document format is not recognized (the content type is 'text/html; charset=utf-8*

My guess was that it was something to do with the 'services' directory not being configured properly but I get the same issue if the service is added to the root of the site.

I have tried aspnet_regiis for both .Net 2 & 4
I'm using Visual Studio 2012 with IIS Express.

**Update:**
It appears that the website is also referencing SharePoint webservices and I have just spotted the following weird message in the error details:

*There was an error downloading `http://localhost:64925/services/TestService.asmx/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata`.
The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.*

Comment: As it says, it's the unrecognised content type. So the type 'asmx' is not registered correctly in IIS, so when the browser requests the link the server thinks 'what the hell is this - I'll serve it as a plain file', hence the download.

Comment: @Stevo Thanks, but how do I fix it running Visual Studio 2012 with IIS Express?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't provide specific guidance (because I don't know). I'd start with looking at the IIS configuration. As you've said it works on a fresh web service outside the site and it works fine, so something in the IIS config is not working correctly. I would look into the differences between existing site and fresh and change settings on the existing one by one to fault find. Sorry I can't be more help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to find the answer.

The Global.asax file had some custom code to rewrite the URL in the `Application_BeginRequest` event handler and this code was not processing requests to .ASMX files correctly.

Simply adding a filter to this logic to exclude .ASMX file types resolved my problem.

Thanks to all who took time to try helping with this.

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried to replicate the issue but to no avail. Returned exactly as expected from the site.

Copied your code directly and pasted it into a blank services document within a .NET 3.5 web forms site.

Do you know if it has created the correct handlers within the web.config file?

```
<httpHandlers>
    <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
    <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
  </httpHandlers>
  <httpModules>
    <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  </httpModules>
```

Just wondering if that might be your issue if it is not telling the browser how to handle the document correctly.

Lee

Comment: Cheers, I have also tried a blank web service project outside of the existing site and that works fine.  I think it must be something specific to the config or the existing website. The handlers look fine in web.config.  I think its something to do with SharePoint, have updated the question.